# Mistakes to avoid while designing PCBs

Tags: circuit-design, pcb-design, simulation, components

I am an electronics hobbyist. I recently  designed and ordered PCBs (using KiCad) but I failed twice. I designed amplifier circuits but something or the other went wrong each time. The problems I faced are:

- I did not have the parts with me before hand. As a result I ended up selecting the wrong footprints and I couldn't find the parts that would fit.
- I made mistakes in the schematic  and running the electrical rules checker showed everything was correct. I only found out about the mistakes after soldering the parts to the board.

The steps I took to avoid these mistakes:

- I simulate the circuit to avoid making mistakes in the schematic.

My questions are:

- How can I find a reliable spice model library? I am currently using a free library I found on GitHub.
- How can I choose among different variants of a part that affect the circuit? For example, for an amplifier operating between -25 V to 25 V there are a variety of N channel MOSFETs that can operate in that voltage range. How would I pick one?

Comment: Reliable SPICE models are obtained from the device manufacturers. I know that LT and TI both tend to have pretty good models for their parts. (most if not all LT models are included in an installation of LTspice, and TI offers theirs for download on the relevant product pages.)

Comment: Choosing the right footprint in Kicad is not always so easy. Measuse the parts and compare with the footprint. And make sure that pins 1,2,3 are in the right order for your part.  It helps a lot printing the pcb in paper and puting the parts on it. And the 3d view, after finding all 3d models.  And after checking everything, check it again.

Comment: @Gos Yes printing it out will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did not have the parts with me before hand. As a result I ended up
> selecting the wrong footprints and I couldn't find the parts that
> would fit.

Create parts so that the symbol and footprint are linked. That way it's easy to generate the BOM and upload it to a supplier to check if everythings in stock.

> I made mistakes in the schematic and running the electrical rules
> checker showed everything was correct. I only found out about the
> mistakes after soldering the parts to the board.

Simulation reveal a lot. You can also program the pins of each symbol to be "passive/input/output", so that the DRC will catch more errors.

> How can I find a reliable spice model library? I am currently using a
> free library I found on GitHub.

By directly downloading them from the manufacturer - that's the first place to get updates to the models. Usually only a handful of critical components really matter.

> How can I choose among different variants of a part that affect the
> circuit? For example, for an amplifier operating between -25 V to 25 V
> there are a variety of N channel MOSFETs that can operate in that
> voltage range. How would I pick one?

Depends on what you want to optimize. If it's price: Search supplier stock for options, sort by price. Rule out the ones that can't handle the current or other parameters and pick the cheapest one.

Other parameters to consider:

- How will you dissipate the heat? Heat sink or through PCB?
- Do you need to mount it manually?
- How much power are you willing to dissipate
- Threshold voltage
- Rds at the gate voltage
- Switching speed
- Gate capacitance
  ...

Answer (score 0):

Most ICs are avialable in several packages.  It is important to ensure that you select a part/package that is actually available from your suppliers before laying out the PCB.  Some of the package variations shown on the datasheet may not actually be available.

For switches, connectors, and other "mechanical" parts, it is desireable to actually have the part in your hand before designing the footprint for it, so you can compare the datasheet's suggested footprint with the actual part.